# How to get emacs to keep cursor in the middle of buffer during search?

Tags: isearch, scrolling

(I am using Aquamacs 3.5 which is based on GNU Emacs 25.3.50.1, in case this matters.)

While searching (`isearch-forward`) in a buffer it often happens that I need to see some lines before/after the matched string.  It happens regularly (as shown in the screenshot below) that the matched string appears at the bottom of the buffer.  In that case I was searching for `[h!]` and there is not even one line showing below the matched line.

[image]

I tried to customise the variable `list-matching-lines-default-context-lines` without success.  In the screenshot above `list-matching-lines-default-context-lines` was set to 5.
I suspect that `isearch` does not pay attention to that variable.

```
list-matching-lines-default-context-lines is a variable defined in ‘replace.el’.
Its value is 5
Original value was 0

Documentation:
Default number of context lines included around ‘list-matching-lines’ matches.
A negative number means to include that many lines before the match.
A positive number means to include that many lines both before and after.
```

Is there a variable I can set to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `C-l` at any time during Isearch, to center the current search hit vertically in the window.